# Variable heights for .slideDown effect loading dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slide, slidedown

I've already looked at a few examples on SO, but to no avail. Probably because my situation is slightly different.

[If you look at this example site](http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/), all the content slides down from the div #panel and dynamic content is loaded in at the same time. It works, but the panel is fixed to 350px no matter what. That's fine if I knew all the content would fit that space, but I know it won't. I need to figure out a formula to have  that div slide down at various heights depending on what content is loaded in.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
jQuery("li.btn-slide a").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel").slideDown( "slow" );
    var post_url = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    var post_id = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    jQuery("#page-con").html("loading...");
    jQuery("#page-con").load(post_url);
    window.location.hash = post_id;
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Again, it works. It's not sliding down 350px no matter what content is there inside of #panel as well as #page-con

Answer (score 0):

Generally slideDown will figure out the height of the element, but as there's no content yet it can't in this case. The solution would be to wait until the content is there to slide the element down.

The height would of course have to be dynamic and adapt to the content for this to work.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("li.btn-slide a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
        var post_id  = $(this).attr("rel");

        $("#page-con").html("loading...")
                      .load(post_url, function() { // content loaded callback

             window.location.hash = post_id;
             $("#panel").slideDown( "slow" ); // now slide it down

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked, but the panel heights are still at 350px. Would I have to change my style for #panel to height: 0 or height: auto?